# How to rewrite logarithmic equation in exponential form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I rewrite this logarithmic equation: $\ln(37)= 3.6109$, in exponential form?

-Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you mean by "logarithmic equation"? The way I see it, it already IS one...

Comment: It looks logarithmic to me already.  Can you give an example of what a logarithmic equation looks like?  Yelling help is not productive.

Comment: Oops, sorry 'bout that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Note that the equation, as given, is not correct.  It is close, but not exact.

Comment: What do you mean by not correct? That is what my textbook said...

Comment: @Jasmine: The actual value of $\ln(37)$ is a real number whose decimal expansion is infinite; it begins
$$\ln(37)=3.6109179126442244443680956710314\ldots$$
So the value 3.6109 is only an approximation to the correct value.

Comment: @Jasmine:  When you use approximate values you need to worry about propagation of errors, which mathematicians rarely do (because their numbers don't have errors).  Subtracting nearly equal numbers is the poster child.  If you subtract 1-0.999 with each number accurate to a part in a million, the difference is accurate to 2 parts in a thousand.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of $\ln(x)$ is that it is the number $y$ such that $e^y=x$. In other words,
$$e^{\ln(x)}=x.$$
We have the equation
$$\ln(37)=3.6109.$$
Because both sides are equal, we have that
$$e^{\ln(37)}=e^{3.6109}.$$
By the definition of $\ln$, this simplifies to
$$37=e^{3.6109}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see it (that is equivalent to Zev's answer) is that
$\log_{b}(a) = x$
is equivalent to
$a = b^x$.

$\ln$ is just $\log_{e}$, so
$\ln(37) = 3.6109$
is simply $\log_b(a) = x$ with
$b = e$, $a = 37$, $x = 3.6109$
and can be rewritten as
$37 = e^{3.6109}$.

That good enough for your needs?

Comment: It is perfect! Thnx a bunch :)